# Javascript no agrega texto al oprimir un botón

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de que por lo menos escriba algo pero resulta que los botones no aparecen en la pantalla, cuando ejecuto el codigo no escribe, no se si el problema esta en la declaracion de las valriables en js.

```js
var primern;
var segundon;
var resultado2;
function init(){
 var pantalla = document.getElementsByClassName('pantalla');
 var igual = document.getElementsByClassName('igual');
 var limpiar = document.getElementsByClassName('limpiar');
 var suma = document.getElementsByClassName('suma');
 var resta = document.getElementsByClassName('resta');
 var multiplicacion = document.getElementsByClassName('multiplicacion');
 var divicion = document.getElementsByClassName('divicion');
 var numero1 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero1');
 var numero2 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero2');
 var numero3 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero3');
 var numero4 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero4');
 var numero5 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero5');
 var numero6 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero6');
    var numero7 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero7');
 var numero8 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero8');
 var numero9 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero9');
 var cero = document.getElementsByClassName('cero');

numero1.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "1";
 }
numero2.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "2";
 }
numero3.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "3";
 }
numero4.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "4";
 }
numero5.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "5";
 }
numero6.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "6";
 }
numero7.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "7";
 }
numero8.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "8";
 }
numero9.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "9";
 }
cero.onclick = function(e){
  pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + "0";
 }
limpiar.onclick = function(e){
 recetear();
    }
suma.onclick = function(e){
 primern = pantalla.textContent;
 resultado2 = "+";
 limpiar();
    }
    resta.onclick = function(e){
     primern = pantalla.textContent;
     resultado2 = "-";
     limpiar();
    }
multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
 primern = pantalla.textContent;
 resultado2 = "*";
 limpiar();
    }
divicion.onclick = function(e){
 primern = pantalla.textContent;
 resultado2 = "/";
 limpiar();
   }
igual.onclick = function(e){
    segundon = pantalla.textContent;
    igual();
}

}
```

```css
table{
    border:solid;
    border-style:ridge;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width:290px;
 display:inline-block;
 top: 200px;
 background:#393333;
 border-radius: 12px
}
td button:hover{
 background:#ccc;
}
td button:active{
 background:#5DADE2;
} 
.pantalla{
 /*color: black;
 border-radius:100px;
 border: solid;
 padding:5px;
 width: 260px;
 background:#EDEDED;*/
 display:block;
 text-align:right;
 font-size:30px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 width:280px;
 height:90px;
 line-height:100px;
 background-color:#fff;
 border-radius:80px;
 margin-top:1px;
 position:relative;
 top:52px;

}
/*td button{
 padding:25px;
}*/
.numero7{
 padding:25px;
 
}
.numero8{
 padding: 25px;

}
.numero9{
 padding: 25px;
}
.numero4{
 padding: 25px;

}
.numero5{
 padding: 25px;
}
.numero6{
 padding: 25px;

}
.numero1{
 padding: 25px;

}
.numero2{
 padding: 25px;

}
.numero3{
 padding: 25px;

}
.divicion{
 padding: 25px;
 width: 64px;

}
.multiplicacion{
 padding: 25px;
 width: 64px;

}
.resta{
 padding: 25px;
 width: 64px;
 
 top:266px;

}
.igual{
 padding: 25px;
 width:64px;

}
.suma{
 padding:25px;

}
.limpiar{
 padding:24px;

}
.cero{
 padding:25px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo/estilo.css">
 
 <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
 <h1>CALCULADORA</h1>
 
 
  
  <table class="Calculadora">
    <tr >
     <td colspan="4"><span class="pantalla"></span></td>  
          </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button class="numero7">7</button></td>
    <td><button class="numero8">8</button></td>
    <td><button class="numero9">9</button></td>
    <td><button class="divicion">%</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button class="numero4">4</button></td>
    <td><button class="numero5">5</button></td>
    <td><button class="numero6">6</button></td>
    <td><button class="multiplicacion">X</button></td>
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button class="numero1">1</button></td>
    <td><button class="numero2">2</button></td>
    <td><button class="numero3">3</button></td>
    <td><button class="resta">-</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button class="limpiar">C</button></td>
    <td><button class="cero">0</button></td>
    <td ><button class="suma">+</button></td>
    <td><button class="igual">=</button></td>
    
    
   </tr>
  </table>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Ralph, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que te falta. En el cuerpo de la pregunta añadir una epxlicacion de lo que intentas, y de qué errores o problemas concretos tienes, para que podamos orientarte sobre ellos. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la publicacion . Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Ralph, podrías decirnos q problema tienes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes que has puesto una clase (class="..") a cada botón, en lugar de un identificador (id="...").

En sí mismo eso no es un error, pero cuando haces

```
var numero1 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero1');
```

no obtienes un elemento: *Get Element**s** by Class Name* (obtener elementos por nombre de clase) devuelve una lista de elementos.

Las formas de solucionarlo más sencillas son:

1. Cambiar class por id en el HTML y pasar a buscar por id:

   ```
   var numero1 = document.getElementById('numero1');
   ```
2. Quedarte con el elemento de la lista:

   ```
   var numero1 = document.getElementsByClassName('numero1')[0];
   ```

Por claridad recomiendo la primera solución, pero la segunda es más rápida.

Comment: Hermano eres un crack.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer, o bien agregarle jquery para poner la funcion onClick en tu btn, o agregar el onClick en el btn html para q llame a la funcion como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<button class="numero6" onclick="nombreDeFuncion(6)">6</button>
```

y despues tenes q hacer una funcion en el js (mismo nombre q le pusiste a la funcion del bton) y le pasas por parametro el valor del boton:

```
function nombreDeFuncion(val){
    pantalla.textContent = pantalla.textContent + val;
}
```

Con las operaciones puedes hacer lo mismo. Al boton le agregas otra funcion y le pasas la "operacion" por parametro:

```
function nombreDeTuFuncion(val){
  primern = pantalla.textContent;
  resultado2 = val;
  limpiar();
}
```

Comment: Usar el atributo `onclick` va en contra del uso de [javascript no obstructivo](http://www.ribosomatic.com/articulos/a-que-te-refieres-con-javascript-no-obstructivo/), no lo recomiendo